# Command "npm run build" not creating the correctely build on VueJS project

Tags: firebase, vue.js, npm, firebase-hosting

I'm developing a simple VueJS app using Firebase hosting. I'm deploy to web using `firebase deploy` after `npm run build`. But when deploy is finished the web page is different from local build using `npm run serve`. I can't understand the reason about it, please help me, I'm newbie with it.

**firebase.json**

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**project structure**

[image]

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "quinta-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.4.4",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.4",
    "vuetify": "^2.2.3",
    "vuex": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.19.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "no-unused-vars": "off",
      "no-console": "off"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ]
}
```

**vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  "transpileDependencies": [
    "vuetify"
  ]
}
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <router-view v-if="isLoggedIn"></router-view>
    <login v-else />
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import login from "@/views/Login"

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    login
  },
  data: () => ({
    isLoggedIn: false
  })
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

**router/index.js**

```
import Login from '@/views/Login'
import Home from '@/views/Home'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home
    },
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'Login',
        component: Login
    }
]

export default new VueRouter({ 
    mode: 'history',
    routes 
})
```

Comment: can you put your package.json here as well ?

Comment: edited @Raymond

Comment: `But when deploy is finished the web page is different from local build` -- this is not clear. How different are they specifically?

Answer (score 0):

From package.json, you can see

`npm run serve` : it's running `vue-cli-service serve` which starts a dev server.

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-serve

`npm run build` : it's running `vue-cli-service build` which produces a production-ready bundle  .

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-build

You may have different setting in dev and production and caused page difference.

Comment: So, where I set up it?

Answer (score 0):

i think it's about of your project config of `publicPath`, it's `'/'` default,
you can see the doc: [Configuration Reference | Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath)

Comment: Oh yes, if I type the path I can browse to the correct page. But my logic not be able to change, I've edited the question with my App.vue

Comment: because you choose vue-router `history` mode, it should work with your server agent:
[the official solution](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)